# Circuit diagram potential issue and help regarding debugging

Tags: circuit-analysis, pspice, schematic

I'm an EE student in my first year, and for my LCA project, we had to buy components and attach all the components of any circuit from the internet. I found one and I've verified my connections many times. How do I verify whether the circuit is even correct or not? Can software like multisim and pspice assist me in this regard? If yes, how?

[image]

Schematic source: [ElectroDuino - PIR Sensor Burglar Alarm System Circuit using 555 Timer IC](https://www.electroduino.com/pir-sensor-burglar-alarm-system-circuit-using-555-timer-ic/)

PIR: Passive Infrared Sensor HC-SR501
Buzzer: Passive Buzzer

The current circuit I've made doesn't make any sound upon detecting motion in front of the sensor.

Comment: This wording is a little confusing. It sounds like you have the physical components already, connected and everything. If that is the case, do you understand the function of this circuit? There are different ways to test if different parts of this circuit are in fact working. If you don't have the parts yet, then yes you can use software to verify this circuit works. Answering the "how" of that is way too open-ended for this website.

Comment: R1 is way too small, try 1k. Have you scoped any signals? Don't have a scope, add some LEDs (to start, put one in series with R1). Do you know what mode the 555 is operating in? (read the datasheet). There are hundreds of PIR sensors and hundreds of buzzers, post a link to their specifications. Are you sure you used a buzzer, not a piezo speaker?

Comment: I had to look up what a PIR sensor is.  Passive Infrared Sensor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor  You should really tell us the specific PIR sensor part number/datasheet.

Comment: We don't know if you have the correct parts. The schematics could work with the right parts but may not work with wrong parts. What do you expect the circuit to do, and what does it do instead? Please note that "it does not work" or "it does nothing" are not correct, it does something and you can observe and debug it. If it emits smoke, then describe from where.

Comment: You have no decoupling here; I suggest adding a handful of μF across the supply rails.

Comment: According to this site: https://lastminuteengineers.com/pir-sensor-arduino-tutorial/ and this sheet: https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf, the pin numbers for the PIR sensor are reversed in your schematic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, but you can do a simulation on any source instead of a sensor
https://forums.ni.com/t5/Multisim-and-Ultiboard/Passive-Infrared-motion-sensor-with-alarm/m-p/2788236#M15689

From user [Tien_P](https://forums.ni.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/81478) on the NI forums linked above:

> Multisim does not have a PIR sensor but you use a voltage control voltage source to emulate it.  You can find voltage control voltage source under "Source" group under the "Controlled voltage source" family.  The input the control source is voltage but you pretend it is the infrared signal.

First, let's set the 555 timer to a frequency of 1 kHz. The output load is 30 ohms (low-power sound emitter). Then we will attach a photosensor, whose photosensitivity is expressed by voltage.

[image: schematic]

Here's the full diagram. The perimeter is 'breached' 100 times per second.

[image: schematic and simulation]